# Linear operator algebra: How to distinguish scalars and operators?

Tags: pattern-matching, symbolic, operators, algebra

In the book "A Physicist' s Guide to Mathematica" Patrick Tam introduces symbolic rules for an algebra of linear operators. Mathematically the **rules** are as follows, where upper (lower) case letters denote operators (scalars).

> identity operator U
>   $AU = U A = A$
>
> Distributive property
>   $A (B + C) = AB + AC$
>   $(A + B) C = AC + BC$
>
> Associative property
>   $A(BC) = (AB)C$
>
> "Scalar property"
>   $A(aB) = a AB$
>   $(aA)B = a AB$

He implements these rules based on the built-in function `NonCommutativeMultiply` as it is already associative and in general noncommutative as required. In Mathematica this might be written as:

```
Unprotect[NonCommutativeMultiply];

A_ ** U := A;
U ** A_ := A;

A_ ** (B_ + C_) := A ** B + A ** C;
(A_ + B_) ** C_ := A ** C + B ** C;

A_ ** ((x_. y_^n_. /; number3Q[x, y, n]) B_) := ((x y^n) A ** B);
((x_. y_^n_. /; number3Q[x, y, n]) A_) ** B_ := ((x y^n) A ** B);

Protect[NonCommutativeMultiply];

number3Q[x_, y_, n_] := NumberQ[x] && NumberQ[y] && NumberQ[n];
```

To tell Mathematica that `a` is a scalar we can write `NumberQ[a]^=True`. Thanks to the pattern `x_. y_^n_.` it will recognise some composite expressions involving `a` as scalars, but for example not `Sqrt[a+1]` or `Sin[a]`. Hence, I have the following **questions**.

1. Is there a more robust way to identify scalar expressions, that only include combinations of mathematical functions and scalars? A scalar is a symbol with `NumberQ[symbol]==True`.
2. Is there a manual way to tell that a full expression is a "number", that it will give `NumberQ[expr]==True`?
3. Is it more advisable to label operators with a special head and treat everything else as scalars, instead of trying to identify scalars? How would an implementation look like?

Comment: Have you tried [NCAlgebra](https://github.com/NCAlgebra/NC)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using NumericQ instead of NumberQ:

```
Unprotect[NonCommutativeMultiply];

A_ ** U := A;
U ** A_ := A;

A_ ** (B_ + C_) := A ** B + A ** C;
(A_ + B_) ** C_ := A ** C + B ** C;

A_ ** (a_ B_) /; NumericQ[a] := a (A ** B)
(a_ A_) ** B_ /; NumericQ[a] := a (A ** B)
A_ ** (B_ a_) /; NumericQ[a] := a (A ** B)
(A_ a_) ** B_ /; NumericQ[a] := a (A ** B)

NumericQ[a] ^= True

Protect[NonCommutativeMultiply];
```

Now `A ** (B Sin[a])` gives,

```
(* A ** B Sin[a] *)
```

which if you look at the FullForm is actually `Times[NonCommutativeMultiply[A,B],Sin[a]]`, i.e. the scalar rule has been applied.

Comment: Hi KraZug and thanks for your nice answer. Is it necessary to specify both A_**(a_ B_) and A_**(B_ a_) patterns? Does pattern matching not include the commutative property of Times? Then it would of course depend on how mathematica orders the terms and we need both patterns.

Comment: Yes, trying it out shows that you don't need to define both options. So you only need the first two lines of the scalar definition.